# Spring batch starts from beginning after restart from dataflow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have developed a simple spring batch application and launching it through spring cloud dataflow.
But when I restart a failed job from dataflow, the batch starts from the beginning instead of continuing from the last execution.
JobLaunch :

```
Map<String,JobParmeter> maps = new HashMap<>();
maps.put("jobID",new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job,new JobParameters(maps));
```

JobConfig :

```
jobBuilderFactory.get("job").start(step).build();
```

Everything else is @Autowired, with no custom configuration. I am using the spring boot app.

If I don't use custom job launcher(JobLaunch in the above code), the batch will always restart. A new instance of a job is never created even if the previous instance is COMPLETED.

Please help me with the correct configuration of the job.

Answer (score 0):

Since you add a new timestamp to job parameters on each run, you get a distinct job instance each time. If you really want to restart a FAILED job instance, you need to pass the same identifying job parameters (`jobID` in your case) of the previous run.

> A new instance of job is never created even if previous instance is COMPLETED.

This is by design. It is not possible to restart a COMPLETED job instance.

Comment: yes I understand this, but I am using spring cloud dataflow to restart a job which should pass same parameters(jobID in my case). I am not passing any parameter manually. But it is creating new job instance id every time I restart a job.